# How to "punch a hole" in a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

Im starting with WPF now, and I dont know if its possible, but it should be.

Im trying to create a fully transparent area in my form, deleting all the contents inside a rectangle (Those contents will be a AxWindowsMediaPlayer, as Shown below), and be able to see whats behind my window.

Its possible in WinForms using TransparencyKey and a Panel, but WinForms doesnt fill my needs for this project.

Example:
[image: Example of "punching a hole" in a window]

Another example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick for you:

```
<Window
        [...]
        Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="400" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush                                                 
        ViewportUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox"
        TileMode="None" 
        ImageSource="/Images/rect.png"
        />
    </Window.OpacityMask>
 <!-- many many controls-->
</Window>
```

`WindowStyle` need to be none

`AllowTransparency` needs to be true

And the image source is just a image with a rectagular transparent part in center. You could also draw this dinamically!

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Opacity="0.1"
    AllowsTransparency="True">   
 </Window>
```

Make WindowStyle="None" and  AllowsTransparency="True" to get transparent window. vary opacity to get amount of transparency

Comment: Yes I got that part, but I will have more elements in the window (A video playing) and I want the rectangle to be transparent in that video too

Comment: Can you post the screen shot of UI. Unable to visualise what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Ive edited my question, and included a GIF showing what I want (That Ive previously made in WinForms)

Comment: @ThiagoSouza If you "got that part" it should've been in your question. Questions should include code of what you have done so far.

Comment: @Nyerguds I understood what they said by controlling opacity, but it didnt solved my problem cause I have more elements in my window.

Answer (score 0):

Got something like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="#66FFFFFF" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#66FFFFFF" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#66FFFFFF" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#66FFFFFF" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="workingRectangle" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/opacity-masks-overview) is probably the closest substitute to Windows Forms' `TransparencyKey`.